# Set DocumentName of a Document from PrintPreviewDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, print-preview

I want to set the title to the document I use in PrintPreviewDialog in Windows Forms. I tried something, but for sure this isn't the way to set the TITLE to this type of Document. Can you help me do this?

```
private void pd_print(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{    
  Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
  gr.DrawString("Sales", new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(40, 40));
}

private void tiparireToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_print);

  PrintPreviewDialog dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
  dlg.Document = pd;
  dlg.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Preview Dialog is just a form where they hid the Text property.

```
PrintPreviewDialog dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
((Form)dlg).Text = "My Title";
dlg.Document = pd;
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: You could set the Text property even without a cast.

Comment: @Jimi, Yes, but the property doesn't show up using intellisense.

Comment: Of cource, the property is `[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` like `Icon` and many other properties (who knows why?). But since it derives from `Form`, you can set all those properties regardless of what Intellisense lets you know.